# didSelectRowAtIndexPath at Intents UI Extension not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sirikit, intents-extension

I have 3 Targets in my app, the main one, an Intents Extension and a Intents UI Extension.

The "Intents UI Extension" target contains an Storyboard with a ViewController containing an UITableView.

When I use the voice shortcut I can see results on the UITableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Is called perfectly and renders my cell, but doesn't matter which cell I select the method is not called.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

After that the app opens as expected with a NSUserActivity (as it should).

**Any ideas on how to get the proper selected cell?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be useful to somebody with the same problem.

In Apple docs says:

> However, your view controllers do not receive touch events or any other events while they are onscreen, and you cannot add gesture recognizers to them. Therefore, never create an interface with controls or views that require user interactions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_ui_extension/configuring_the_view_controller_for_your_custom_interface

In other words, you can use a table view but all cells are going to respond in the same way...